# Approved syntax for C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

C++20 has plenty of new features. Between them, concepts are quite useful. I already know that there are some ways on using concepts.

1. By writing `requires`:

   ```
   template<typename T> requires MyConcept<T> // some other stuff
   ```
2. By using it on the `template` angle brackets:

   ```
   template<MyConcept T>
   // some other stuff
   ```

However, I know there was another way of writing concepts, which is kinda syntatic sugar. I saw it used on a talk and as I learned later, the syntax was still being discussed because "concept functions are `template` functions, but the syntax didn't show that". The syntax is like this:

```cpp
void myFunc(myConcept auto t) // blah blah
```

My question is, was this syntax approved for C++20?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template looks like it

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The syntax that really didn't show that was `void myFunc(myConcept t);`. The `auto` there makes the accepted syntax unambiguous. That is to say the discussion you remember was primarily before the `auto` was added.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#18